# How can I get a list of all of the user databases via t-sql?

Tags: sql-server

I want to get a list of all of the user databases from an mssql server instance. What's the best way to do this?

I know I can select from sys.databases, but I don't see any way to filter out system databases besides hardcoding a list of names to exclude.

I need the script to work on 2000/2005 and 2008.

If the approach I listed above is the only way to go, what are list of names I should exclude? I don't know if 2005 or 2008 added any new system databases off the top of my head.

Answer (score 22):

Was looking in to this again today and decided to profile what Management Studio was doing to populate the Object Explorer details.

[image: Object Explorer > System Databases]

Turns out the solution Microsoft have implemented is pretty simplistic and boils down to the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM   master.sys.databases
WHERE  Cast(CASE WHEN name IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb') THEN 1 ELSE is_distributor END As bit) = 0
```

Please note that this was performed using **SSMS 2008R2** (10.50.4033.0).

Answer (score 10):

On SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, looks like I cannot reliably use any of the above methods.  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA only shows me information in the current database, db_id (database_id) #5 is my first user database, and owner_sid on two of my user databases on one of my mirrored databases (running on SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard) shows owner_sid = 1 for my two most recently created databases. (PablolnNZ's comment above is correct: I did not set an explicit owner for those two databases so it still shows as having an owner of 'sa'.)

The only reliable means I was able to use was the following:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'tempdb', 'msdb', 'Resource')
```

Answer (score 9):

The first query will return a table with data regarding all of the databases on the instance:

```
Select * 
From sys.databases
```

From this table you'll notice you can narrow down the scope of data you're looking for by using the `WHERE` clause. For example, the following queries will essentially return the same result table (the one you're most likely looking for):

```
Select * 
From sys.databases 
Where database_id > 5


Select * 
From sys.databases 
Where len(owner_sid)>1
```

These queries will work in SQL Server 2008 and 2012.

Comment: A word of warning on using the database_id like this. On my instance of SQL Express without reporting services, database_id=5 is a user database, so using > 5 would not pick it up. On another instance that has reporting services, id 5 = ReportServer$SQL1TempDB. Also using len(owner_sid) > 1 will pick up ReportServer$SQL1 and ReportServer$SQL1TempDB if reporting services are installed. Finally note that if you have not set the owner of a user database (e.g. maybe restored from one server to another) it will have an owner_sid = 0x01 so len(owner_sid)>1 will not pick it up.

Comment: This is NOT the solution, none of the solutions described above are reliable

Comment: Must be database_id >= 5 or database_id > 4, as normally 1 = master, 2 = model, 3=msdb and 4 = tempdb.

Answer (score 5):

This works in 2005, not 100% sure about the other versions but I think it will fly.  It's a bit of a hack but might get you what you need:

```
 select * from sys.databases where len(owner_sid)>1
```

Comment: I tested it on my installation of SQL2K8 and it worked fine. Seems kinda hacky, but it did return the correct result.

Comment: Definately "hacky" and there is no way to ensure this would work in future versions of SQL.

Answer (score 3):

As nasty as it sounds to hardcode things. The names and number of system databases has been fairly consistent for several versions of SQL. However, if that is too unpleasant you could semi-hardcode them into a table and then plug that into your query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can offhand.  One note -- on 2k you'll have to use master.dbo.sysdatabases and not master.sys.databases (which doesn't exist in 2k).

Comment: Is there a way the script can tell what version of SQL server it's being executed on and branch?

Comment: select @@version is one way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2008 you have access to a view called [sys.databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which when joined with [sys.server_principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can eliminate the databases owned by **sa**, which you can (most often) safely discern are the "system databases". Thus, allowing you to filter these items out.

```
select
  d.name
  ,d.database_id
from
  sys.databases d
join
  sys.server_principals p
  on p.sid = d.owner_sid
where
  p.name <> 'sa';
```

Comment: This will also include databases of which the owner was changed to sa. This will be done often, since users will leave a company, and then their account is removed. The sa account remains.