# loop script is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm just trying to create tables in user databases apart from system databases.

here is the script

```
Declare @V table (ID INT,name varchar(100))

DECLARE 
    @DatabaseName VARCHAR(50),
    @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
INSERT INTO @V(Id,name)

select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY NAME),
        name  
    from sys.databases 
            where database_id >= 5

 DECLARE @LoopCounter INT , @MaxId INT, 
         @Name NVARCHAR(100)
SELECT  @LoopCounter = min(id) , 
        @MaxId = max(Id) 
FROM @V

WHILE(@LoopCounter IS NOT NULL
      AND @LoopCounter <= @MaxId)
BEGIN
   SELECT @Name = Name
   FROM @V WHERE Id = @LoopCounter

   set  @Name  = @DatabaseName

   SET @SQL = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)
+'CREATE TABLE T(ID INT)';


   SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1  
    -- PRINT(@DatabaseName);
    --PRINT(@SQL);  
    EXECUTE(@SQL)
END
```

why is it not creating table dynamically?

how to get  only user databases in below script

instead of giving manually

```
     DECLARE @Sql AS VARCHAR(4000)
        SET @Sql = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''tempdb'',''model'',''msdb'',''ReportServer'',''ReportServerTempDB'') 
                                EXECUTE (''

     USE [?] CREATE TABLE T (ID INT)'')'
                            EXEC sp_MSforeachdb

 @command1 = @Sql
```

Comment: You should use this instead: [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Comment: yes i have that script but need to do in this  loop scriipt @aaron

Comment: Isn't that going to create something like `USE MYDB1CREATE TABLE`? Also, instead of all the loop counters etc. you could just use cursor.

Comment: please find the msforeach script but how can i add select 
        name  
    from sys.databases statement in the ms script

Comment: @JamesZ i'm unable to move forward can you please suggest me

Comment: Well I already did. Shouldn't you tell me if that was the reason or not?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68867/changing-databases-dynamically-using-variables  this may can help you

Comment: yes it will create like that but how can i achieve that instead of cursors @JamesZ

Comment: Sorry, can't help you if you don't even tell what's wrong or answer to me if the problem is with your `create` word or not.

Comment: @dlatikay There is a space after use, but not between the database name and create. Other problem is that `@DatabaseName` is never assigned any values. The print statement should have shown that.

Comment: the missing space between the database name and the `CREATE TABLE` statement looks suspicious, but due to `QUOTENAME` it still works: just tested, the parser does not mind the missing space between the closing square bracket and the following statement. failing to ever assign to `@DatabaseName` right, should've seen that earlier

Comment: @JamesZ it will create with spaces USE DB1 CREATE TABLE T (ID INT). in this script l'm trying to achieve creating table T in DB1,DB2 etc apart from system databases

Comment: @dlatikay yes i'm unable to assign to DatabaseName. where i'm missing

Comment: why it is got negative voted till i don't know

Comment: @mohan111 I think its because it took so many comments until the problem became really clear. Now downvotes could be undone, but they are locked in until the question is edited again. IMO the first part could almost be close-voted as "just a typo" (accepted answer), whereas the second part is valid, but has been asked and answered before (see 2nd answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems with your script are here:

```
WHILE(@LoopCounter IS NOT NULL
      AND @LoopCounter <= @MaxId)
BEGIN
   SELECT @Name = Name
   FROM @V WHERE Id = @LoopCounter

   --set  @Name  = @DatabaseName -- this will assign value from @DatabaseName into @Name, but you should do the vice versa:

    set  @DatabaseName = @Name

   SET @SQL = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)
+' CREATE TABLE T(ID INT)'; -- I would also add space here, it might work with [XXX]create table


   SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1  
    -- PRINT(@DatabaseName);
    --PRINT(@SQL);  
    EXECUTE(@SQL)
END
```

Because @DatabaseName was null, the result of your @SQL was null, and executing null is most likely just ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your draft of the version with the `sp_MSforeachdb` procedure was also fine; you asked for a version without writing the names of the system databases. Unfortunately this has still not been implemented - there is no reliable flag or property on a database that would clearly identify it as a user database. Microsoft themselves apply the (inverted) criteria I am using below, when they list the contents of the "System Databases" folder in SSMS... see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28590305/1132334

```
SELECT 
  [name] 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE CAST(CASE WHEN [name] IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') THEN 1 ELSE is_distributor END AS bit)=0
```

Here is a tested script:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SET @sql='IF ''?'' IN (SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE CAST(CASE WHEN [name] IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'') THEN 1 ELSE is_distributor END AS bit)=0) 
    EXECUTE (''USE [?] CREATE TABLE T (ID int)'')'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = @Sql
```