# Get non-system DB names

Tags: sql, sql-server

ALL,

I just tried the query found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-a-list-of-databases-on-an-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#TsqlProcedure), but it gave me all names.

How do I filter out system databases names?

TIA!

EDIT:

The suggested solutions contains hardcoded values, either names or hardcoded number.
However, those are different depending on some other parameters.

Comment: WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')   ...  or ...   database_id>4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a list of all of the user databases via t-sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463118/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-of-the-user-databases-via-t-sql)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, Are there only 4? For all versions of MS SQL?

Comment: @Dai, no it doesn't. It uses a hardcoded name or the hardcoded constant

Comment: The linked answer is too old for this to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Igor - I would invite you to either refute the answer provided by Dai with a reason why it doesn't work or accept that that's the logic that MS uses.

Comment: @BenThul, I accepted the answer from Roger as he gave a full and concise explanation of what is happening. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Microsoft will add `is_ms_shipped` column to the `sys.databases` system view, there will be no complete answer to your question.

The 4 default system databases have already been mentioned earlier. Their names are locked, so you can hardcode them pretty safely. Other databases not created explicitly by users are (the answer is valid for up to SQL Server 2019, and possibly 2022 versions):

- Replication distributor: has `sys.databases.is_distributor = 1`
- SSISDB: there is no simple solution here, as afaik the database name can be changed during SSIS installation. Your best bet is probably hardcoding the default.

Things that are not user databases in the strict sense:

- Database shapshots: have `sys.databases.source_database_id is not null`
- Schema and statistics-only copy of a database: the query `select databasepropertyex('MyDbName', 'IsClone')` returns 1.

NB: Because Microsoft adds new features in every major version of SQL Server, this answer should not be considered 100% complete in the future.

Comment: understood. Thx for the explanation. Let's blame MS for not having that column. 

Answer (score 0):

There have typically been 4 system databases in a normal sql sever install for the last couple of decades.

These are master, model, msdb and tempdb and they have used IDs 1 through 4.

There are other system databases that you may run into, distribution or SSIDDB for example. These do not follow any particular ID patterns as it can depend on when they were installed, and what may have been created on that server prior to the installation.

For the most part, ignoring IDs 1 though 4  will, on most versions of SQL Server ignore those 4 system databases, but this doesn't mean there are not additional ones installed.

Comment: @PatrickHirst, the keyword here is `typically` and so basically it looks like there is no way to filter out the system DBs reliably without hardcoding anything, right?